# Selenium IDE - Login prompt Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

I have a website that I need to login with an user and password, like this:

[image]

So, I almost resolved this issue by using this command:

```
Command: open

Target: https://user@password@URL
```

Example:

```
https://user@domain.com@password@google.com
```

The problem is that Firefox stills want me to confirm the login by showing this:

[image]

Is there any way to bypass or disable this confirmation in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Basically this kind of confirmation not came up with Other Browser. For Firefox you need to do certain config setting, so that pop will not came, Please do the following setting in your Browser,

```
Navigate to the URL about:config.
Click past the warning of harmful consequences.
Type negotiate-auth into the filter at the top of the page, in order to remove most of the irrelevant settings from the list.
Double-click on network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris. A dialogue box for editing the value should appear.
Enter the required hostname(s) and/or URL prefix(es) then click OK.
```

That all. Hope this will work for you.. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help :-) ... I did the steps but the pop-up is still showing ... is there a way to send you a message showing the server address that I'm using? so I don't have to post public here